# Analytics along with OLTP Database

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a primary use case where I want to have a transactional relational database for which I am using Postgres.

I also need to run frequent aggregate queries (count, sum, average) on the data. These statistics cannot be precomputed as there are multiple filters for search that we have to provide.

I was initially thinking of using Redshift as a secondary storage, which can serve these queries, but then I would also need to build a system to keep the data in sync between the two storages.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you verify that your current Postgres server can't handle those queries in a timely manner? Especially Postgres 11 with it's improved support for parallel queries and JIT might be enough if you have good hardware.

Comment: Some initial tests did not give us the desired result. Although, we might get similar results with Redshift itself. We have tables which have around 200 GB data in total and some requests for count queries take as much as 10 seconds. In comparison, as our data retrieval is paginated we are able to provide results in milliseconds.

Comment: Also we currently have Postgres 9.6 but we can consider upgrading also.

Comment: Note that Postgres 12 will have generated columns: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/generated-columns-in-postgresql-12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at AWS DMS, you can set this up to keep a near real time replica of your Postgres data on Redshift.

It is reliable and requires minimal maintenance (e.g. if you add new columns to your source data).

Read both of these carefully, especially limitations and requirements.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html
and
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html

Unless you need them, I recommend excluding text (and other large object) columns from the sync. this can be done easily by setting a flag, or can be tailored column by column.

The source Postgres database does not have to be held on AWS.